# I want to parse long text documents into an SQLite DB. How do I escape all unsupported characters?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, parsing, cordova

I am very new to SQLite. For my PhoneGap project, I have multiple long text documents that I will parse into an SQLiteDB on first run, using JavaScript. These text documents could contain any characters, but the documents are stable: I have the documents in hand, they will not be dynamically updated.

My questions are:

1. Is there a list of all of the unsafe characters that will need to be escaped? I have searched, but can't find one- only articles referring to individual unsafe characters like ' and %.
2. Is it a better approach to search & replace through the documents before parsing, to escape the unsafe characters, or better to do this in the process of parsing?

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%` is unsafe only in LIKE patterns, where it can be [escaped](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like).

`'` is unsafe in any string literal, where it can be escaped by doubling it.
However, instead of trying to escape it, just use parameters:

```js
String document = "$%&/)';|<\"@...";
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO MyTable(id, doc) VALUES(?, ?)",
              [12345, document]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! I will be using INSERT INTO to store chunks of text, which could include $, ;, :, ', %, >, <, and /. Are you saying that I only need to pay attention to escaping the ' when storing, and the % when retrieving using LIKE?

Comment: Sorry, I just read your answer through again and saw that you show the use of parameters to safely INSERT any of those characters. I will use this approach, thank you.